# How to use the epsilon-delta definition to prove the limit

Tags: real-analysis

Use the $\varepsilon,\delta$ definition of the limit of a function to prove that $$\lim_{x\to1} \sqrt{x^2+2} = \sqrt{3}$$

I am not sure how to approach this problem since it has square roots involved, usually I would try to find a way to factor to move a part to the epsilon. But the square root doesn't allow me to factor like I have previously.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the conjugate expression:
$$\Bigl|\sqrt{x^2+2}-\sqrt{3}\Bigr|=\Biggl|\frac{x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^2+2}+\sqrt{3}}\Biggr|\le \frac{|x^2-1|}2$$
since we know $\sqrt2,\sqrt 3>1$. Can you take it from there?